# Sci-fi/fantasy short short story translated from French: lovers that turn out to be robots

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots, soft-sci-fi, translation

I'm interested in locating this short short story that was in one of the many collections I devoured as a teenager in the 80s. Sci-fi/ fantasy, translated from French, I think. But the collection as a whole was American. Two lovers, a man and a woman, exploring each other's bodies, and the woman discovers a button in an out-of-way-at spot on the man's torso. The woman wonders aloud and gives it a push and hears a pleasant masculine chime. They puzzle over the implications. Is he a robot? Does it matter?
He in turn discovers a similar button on her which produces a feminine note when pushed. Further philosophical pondering, ending with a cheerful "oh, well..."

Comment: The man discovers the woman's button first, and is very concerned, imagining that she is some sort of alien — she then discovers his button, and he promptly decides that everything is fine! (and his button has a more 'masculine' tome).
I believe I read this in Fantasy and Science Fiction Magazine.